# How to turn every object on my Artboard into different layers in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I drew a popsicle and I want to animate it in After Effects but first I need to separate each object on my drawing into a new different layer

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the Layers palette, *highlight your desired layer* choose the "Release to Layers" command. The "Build/Sequence" options of this command could be useful to you in different workflows. Sequence simply takes each of your art and places it into a layer of their own. Build will make a 'pyramid' of your art, with the art being duplicated with all pieces at the top and only the last piece at the bottom. I find it hard to describe, but see my attached screenshots.

[image]
The command is in the flyout menu.

[image]
Here is how my artwork starts out.

[image]
Here is the command done in Sequence mode

[image]
And here the command is done in Build mode.

For your animation project, this may help!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to manually select each element and then either `CTRL+X` (Cut) and `CTRL+V` (Paste) them onto a new layer or just drag the element to a new layer as in my example below.

[image]